# History of the Wreath product

Tags: mathematics, terminology, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why is the [wreath product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product) so named?

If possible, please provide a citation.

Comment: [Cross-posted from Mathematics.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177271/name-of-wreath-product)

Comment: Not a direct answer, but at http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Biographies/Kaluznin.html they write that Kaluznin introduced wreath products of abstract groups while Jordan, Specht, and Polya had earlier worked with wreath products of permutation groups.

Comment: In a footnote on p. 164 of Harary's "Graph Theory" (online at http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/705364.pdf) it says Polya called it Gruppenkranz and Littlewood introduced the name wreath product in his book "Theory of Group Characters" (1940).

Comment: That is Littlewood as in Littlewood-Richardson rule, not as in Hardy and Littlewood.